# import template style with listing : getNumberingDefinitionsPart() return null for WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage()

Tags: docx4j

i have some problems importing styles from a docx template.
I want to extract these styles to apply it to my new document.
Most of them have a numbering.

I can extract the style and numbering correctly from template.
I can apply styles but can t apply numbering as my wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getNumberingDefinitionsPart() return null

If I try to not import NumberingDefinitionPart, all my styles implying listing with number turn to be considered as list without number (and that s not what I want).

I can t find a way to instanciate it and there is not method to set a new one.
Here is my code.

```
public class ModuleToDocxGenerator {
    private WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = null;
    private XHTMLImporter xHTMLImporter = null;
    private List<String> listStyle;
    private ProjectType project;
    private File file;
    private Map<String, Object> mapElement = new HashMap<>();
    private int taillePolice = 12;
    private final String police = "Arial";
    private Map<String, String> mapBookmark = new HashMap<>();
    private int compteurIDBookMark = 1;

    public void docxParser() {

        // Récupération des styles du template
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage2 = null;
        try {
            wordMLPackage2 = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File("template.docx"));
        } catch (Docx4JException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        MainDocumentPart tempDocPart = wordMLPackage2.getMainDocumentPart();
        //add Style part
        StyleDefinitionsPart sdp = tempDocPart.getStyleDefinitionsPart();
        Styles tempStyle = null;
        // Add numbering part
        NumberingDefinitionsPart ndp = tempDocPart.getNumberingDefinitionsPart();
        Numbering numbStyle = null;
        try {
            tempStyle = sdp.getContents();
            numbStyle=ndp.getContents();
        } catch (Docx4JException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getNumberingDefinitionsPart().setJaxbElement(numbStyle);
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getStyleDefinitionsPart().setJaxbElement(tempStyle);
```

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/NumberingRestart.java#L54

You need something like:

```
// Add numbering part
NumberingDefinitionsPart ndp = new NumberingDefinitionsPart();
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(ndp);
ndp.setJaxbElement( (Numbering) XmlUtils.unmarshalString(initialNumbering) );
```